# Is it possible to declare a QWidget as a child of a window created outside of Qt?

Tags: qt, window, native, handle

I'd like to use Qt in my browser plugin, but I don't get to create my own window, the browser does.

What I'd like to do is create a QWidget as a child of a native window handle... Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to take over a native window handle by calling [`QWidget::create()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwidget.html#create) in your custom widget's constructor. Note that it's a protected method so you can't call it on a normal `QWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a dialog and not an embedded window it's relatively easy. Call `QWidget::winId()` on your top-level widget. In Qt4 this will return a `WId`, which is a preprocessor definition for `HWND`. In Qt5, `WId` is a typedef for `HWND`, so you have to perform an explicit cast:

```
HWND hwnd = (HWND)widget->winId()
```

Unfortunately, the functionality in Qt5 is currently unreliable/partially broken. As of Qt 5.4.1, it's not resolved and there's a note in the source that `QWidget::winId()` is "going away". note that this issue primarily affects embedded native windows in a Qt app, not vice versa. Your mileage may be better.

Note: `QWidget::create()` is intended for embedding native windows in Qt. It probably does not apply in your situation.

Answer (score -2):

Only if you can cast it as a QWidget.

Comment: There's NO WAY you should cast anything from the native OS to a QWidget.

Comment: Does QWidget::create produce the parent/child relationship OP wants?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know but I suppose so. Now if the window already contains its own UI elements (buttons, etc) then I don't think those will  be automatically converted into corresponding QWidgets. You'd best start with a new, empty window.